React.jsのアプリケーションにアイモバイル様の広告を統合する方法を教えていただけますでしょうか？
自社のReact.jsのアプリケーションにアイモバイル様の広告を統合しようとしているのですが、上手くプラットフォームに広告を表示することができません。
https://www.i-mobile.co.jp/index.html
以下は、アイモバイル上で作成したネイティブSP広告に関連するコードです。

※コード
scriptsAdded.current = true
setTimeout(() => {
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.type = 'text/javascript'
script.innerHTML = imobile_spot_info = { pid : "82344", asid : "1862285", display_area : [{ target_element:"#imobile_ad_display", template:"<a href='{{click_url}}'><img class='radius' src='{{image_url}}'></a>", }] };
document.body.appendChild(script)
}, 1000)

ネットワークタブからJavaScriptが正常に読み込まれていることを確認できます。しかし、広告は表示されていません。
どなたか、React.jsアプリでアイモバイル様の広告を実装したことがある方はいらっしゃいますか？ご意見やアドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。
